# Attaching to a JVM started by ProcessBuilder failed

Tags: java, jvm, jmx

I am comparing the memory consumption of two implementations of an API in a big system. In order to minimize impact from other parts of the system, I run the function in a Process started by ProcessBuilder, connect to the new Process using JMX, then use MemoryMXBean to monitor its memory consumption. Here's the code I use:

```
val pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/java",
  "-cp", "/home/ubuntu/main.jar",
  "-Xmx8G", "dataset.feature.EncMemoryUsageProcess",
  param1, param2)
val process = pb.start()
val pidfield = process.getClass.getDeclaredField("pid")
pidfield.setAccessible(true)
val pid = pidfield.get(process).toString

// Attach VM and obtain MemoryMXBean
val vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid)
var connectorAddr = vm.getAgentProperties.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress")
if (connectorAddr == null) {
  val agent = vm.getSystemProperties.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "management-agent.jar"
  vm.loadAgent(agent)
  connectorAddr = vm.getAgentProperties.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress")
}
val serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(connectorAddr)
val connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL)
val mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection
val mbeanName = new ObjectName(ManagementFactory.MEMORY_MXBEAN_NAME)
val memoryMXBean = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbsc, mbeanName, classOf[MemoryMXBean])

var maxMemory = 0l

while (process.isAlive) {
  Thread.sleep(200l);
  val memoryUsage = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed
  maxMemory = Math.max(memoryUsage, maxMemory);
}

return maxMemory
```

However, the code throws "com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded" when I call `VirtualMachine.attach`. I googled and noticed this is generally caused by not having a pid file generated, and one common cause is that the new JVM is not created by the same user. However, this seems like not my case as I am creating the new JVM as a subprocess.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

## Update

I have noticed that this error only occurred when I start multiple Processes like the following(the code listed above is `executeAndAttach`):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5;i++) {
    executeAndAttach(i, param);
}
```

The first time I do executeAndAttach, it will succeed, but subsequent calls all throw the exception. More weird, when I debug in the LinuxVirtualMachine.findSocketFile(), where is the place the exception was thrown out, the error disappears.

Comment: Could it be the JVM's are different Arch's ? i.e 32 vs 64 ?

Comment: @Nicholas I am running on a machine with only one JDK installed. It's Oracle JDK 1.8.0_131 64-bit. I also manually executed "/usr/bin/java -version" to double confirm that the parent process and subprocess are running on the same JDK

Comment: Try adding `-XX:+StartAttachListener` option to the command line of the remote Java process. Will it help?

Comment: @apangin Unfortunately this does not help. Thank you all the same!

Comment: Is there `.java_pidXXX` socket file in `/tmp` directory?

Comment: When I debug the program, for each iteration the pid file is there, and everything work well. Only when I run the program, this error occurs. The subprocess I started does not last long, so it's hard to check whether they are there during program running.